# Batch loop to identify files with _1 in the filename - erroneous needs 3 executions to work

Tags: loops, batch-file

I'm trying to merge thousands of pdf-files in a folder using pdftk.

The problem is I have to run the code three times in order to work one time and it only works for the last eligible set of files.(It should be run one time and do it for all pairs of pdfs, but it only works for the last set in the alphabet)

Here is my code:

```
SET _identifier=_1.pdf
FOR /F "delims==" %%F in ('dir /b ^| find "%_identifier%"') do (
SET _test=%%F
ECHO %_test%
SET _result=%_test:~0,-6%
ECHO %_result%
pdftk A=%_result%_1.pdf B=%_result%_2.pdf cat output %_result%.pdf
REN %_result%_1.pdf %_result%_XX.pdf
REN %_result%_2.pdf %_result%_XY.pdf 
)
```

First I'm creating a variable with _1.jpg in it (if there is a _1, there is a file with *_1.pdf, there is also one called *_2.pdf)
Then it should go line by line and look for files ending with _1.pdf. For those I create a variable with the full file name, remove the last 6 characters (aka "_1.pdf") and pass this shortened name on the the PDF merger.
afterwards I rename(delete) the old files.

So what am I missing?

A workaround would be a loop that counts the files in the directory and executes the other code n-times, but that seems to be a dirty solution (and would not help me figuring out where my mistake is)

Background: 
I got thousand of pdfs in a folder, some should be multi page pdfs some are fine already.

The file names look like this:

```
AA1234L_AA1_1.pdf
AA1234L_AA1_2.pdf
AA2345LBB1_1.pdf
AA2345LBB1_2.pdf
DD2023A.pdf
```

and should look like this afterwards:

```
AA1234L_AA1.pdf
AA2345LBB1.pdf
DD2023A.pdf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use delayed expansion inside your `FOR` loop. At a command line, type `SET /?` for an explanation about delayed expansion.

Add this line before the `FOR` loop:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
```

Then, change references to variables to use `!` instead of `%`, like this:

```
SET _identifier=_1.pdf
FOR /F "delims==" %%F in ('dir /b ^| find "%_identifier%"') do (
  SET _test=%%F
  ECHO !_test!
  SET _result=!_test:~0,-6!
  ECHO !_result!
  pdftk A=!_result!_1.pdf B=!_result!_1.pdf cat output !_result!.pdf
  REN !_result!_1.pdf !_result!_XX.pdf
  REN !_result!_2.pdf !_result!_XY.pdf 
)
```